# .NET Core: How to Output String from StreamReader as XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Doing a project in .Net Core 2, using MVC, I'm attempting to incorporate a project from GitHub that generates the XML for an RSS feed. It is TAlex.RSSFeedGenerator.

To generate the actual document, the FeedGenerator's only option is serializing its RSS object to a MemoryStream:

```
public void Generate(Rss rss, Stream output)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rss));
  serializer.Serialize(output, rss);
}
```

So FeedGenerator has already serialized the RSS content as XML in Stream, and I want to return that content as XML from an MVC Controller ( `return Ok(content_here)` ).

How can I do this?

As incorporated originally / currently:

```
var rss = new Rss();
// ...
var RssFeedGenerator = new FeedGenerator();
var output = new MemoryStream();
RssFeedGenerator.Generate(rss, output);
output.Position = 0;
var sreader = new StreamReader(output);
return Ok(sreader.ReadToEnd());
```

This puts out a string and is seen as a string by the browser. It is not seen as XML or RSS.

The MVC Controller is defined and decorated like so:

```
[HttpGet()]
[Produces("text/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync() {...}
```

So, I need the string that is already an XML document to be recognized as an XML document, not a string. My goal is also to send the contents as a response directly, not save it to a file and then have to redirect the user to that file or have to have Ok() read from the file.

Also, I can't send the MemoryStream directly to Ok(), because I get an error that one can't access a closed stream.

The browser is currently showing this:

```
<string>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt; ... </string>
```

(Originally, it was properly decoding the HTML entities, so you'd see:

```
<string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> ... </string>
```

but now it's not even doing that.)

Comment: you want to return RSS as XML text?

Comment: I changed `[Produces(...)]` to `[Produces("application/rss+xml")]`. It was originally the rss+xml, but I think I changed it while troubleshooting an unrelated issue earlier today, and missed changing it back once I moved to a site I could access.

Comment: I've included what the browser is showing in the question above.

Comment: @Umang I have an object that represents the RSS feed. It will generate the text that is the XML document, but I'm trying to get .Net or MVC or IActionResult or whomever to recognize that what it is receiving is or should be XML.

Comment: @Umang Perhaps to rephrase the question yet another way, what does IActionResult expect to receive in order to successfully serialize its input as XML? If I have an object that already is XML, represented as a string, why doesn't IActionResult serialize it correctly as XML?

Comment: Is this webapi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying.

Please return ContentResult in order to see the RSS XML. You can have "application/xml" or "application/RSS+XML" or "text/xml"

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        string rssFeed = "<?xml >...";
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = rssFeed,
            ContentType = "application/RSS+xml"
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'll give the other post a look. The MemoryStream isn't actually used like this. It is in a using statement within another function, where the function handles the RSSFeedGenerator stuff entirely, and returns only the string from ReadToEnd().

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It is informative, because what you pointed me to is basically what the Generate() method is already doing -- just to a Stream obj instead of a StringWriter obj. I implemented an extension function for FeedGenerator, which returns the string from StringWriter, but the problem is still the same. Ok() still sends the string from StringWriter so that the browser sees it as a string, not XML.

Comment: Note the example from the browser that I added to the original question, if that helps with understanding what I'm seeing.

Comment: Looking at your output, Have you thought of returning content result. Something like this:  return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content =<xml>...</xml>,
            ContentType = "text/xml",
        };
Let me know if that works, I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, I think something along those lines -- bypassing MVC's ActionResults -- will be good to try.

Comment: Yes, that exact combo works: ContentResult + text/xml (Don't know if anything else might work. But ContentResult + application/rss+xml does not.)

Comment: how are you calling the the endpoint? Just wondering if you need to have a middleware to allow 'application/RSS+xml' mime type

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In Startup, the only specific thing I applied is the XmlSerializerOutputFormatter().

Comment: do you need the content type to be "application/rss+xml"? Can your content-type not be  just "application/xml"?

Comment: "application/xml" works as well. Just tested it. I went with "text/xml" because of another thread where that seemed to be the concensus (at the time) about which MimeType worked best for RSS relative to browsers.